# react-native fetch return status code + json

Tags: react-native, promise, fetch-api

I use fetch in react-native to make API calls.

I need to get status code (200 , 401, 404 ) and the response data.

This work to get the response data :

```
return fetch(url)
.then(response => {
  return response.json();
})
.then(res => {
  console.log("reponse :", res); // <-------- res is ok with data
 })    .catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
  return { name: "network error", description: "" };
});
```

Now i tweak the first then to get the status code but data is not what i except

```
return fetch(url)
.then(response => {
  const statusCode = response.status;
  const data = response.json();
  return { statusCode, data };
})
.then(res => {
  console.log("reponse :", res); // <-------- i get a "promise"
 }).catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
  return { name: "network error", description: "" };
});
```

the console log :

```
  {statusCode: 200, data: Promise}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`response.json()` returns a promise, you should wait until it will be fulfilled. To do that you can use `Promise.all` with array of two elements: `statusCode` and `response.json()` call:

```
return fetch(url)
  .then(response => {
    const statusCode = response.status;
    const data = response.json();
    return Promise.all([statusCode, data]);
  })
  .then(([res, data]) => {
    console.log(res, data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    return { name: "network error", description: "" };
  });
```

//EDIT
you can create a function who process the response

```
function processResponse(response) {
  const statusCode = response.status;
  const data = response.json();
  return Promise.all([statusCode, data]).then(res => ({
    statusCode: res[0],
    data: res[1]
  }));
}
```

and use it the then()

```
 return fetch(url)
    .then(processResponse)
    .then(res => {
        const { statusCode, data } = res;
        console.log("statusCode",statusCode);
        console.log("data",data);
    }) .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    return { name: "network error", description: "" };
  });
```

Comment: thanks for help.
I get a syntax error with `then([res, data] => {` 
I change it to `.then((res, data) => {  console.log(res, data);  })`  but this log `undefined undefined`

Comment: what kind of error did you get? I use _destructing_ syntax to get the names of variables. If it's unsupported by your node.js version, use array indexes: `.then(res => console.log(res[0], res[1])`.

Comment: this is the error :
`error: bundling failed: ..services.js: Unexpected token, expected , (176:22) 
  174 |       return Promise.all([statusCode, data]);
  175 |     })
> 176 |     .then([res, data] => {
      |                       ^
  177 |       console.log(res, data);
  178 |     })
  179 |     .then(json => {`

Comment: otherwise the following code work for me thanks a lot : 
`.then(response => {
      const statusCode = response.status;
      const data = response.json();
      return Promise.all([statusCode, data]);
    })
    .then(res => {
      return {statusCode:res[0], data:res[1]}
    })
    .then(json => {
      console.log("reponse :", json); ...`

Comment: is there a way to create a function that i can use i my other fetch and who do this two steps : `.then(response => {
      const statusCode = response.status;
      const data = response.json();
      return Promise.all([statusCode, data]);
    })
    .then(res => {
      return {statusCode:res[0], data:res[1]}
    })` ?

Comment: Yes of course it's possible. You can use this code above, and create a function from it, this function will accept one parameter - `url`, and return a promise.

Comment: sorry i mean a function than i can use in the then() like `fetch(url).then(mergeStatusAndData).then( res=> {   /* use data after desctructuring */ } )`

Comment: Something like that: `function processResponse(response) {
  const statusCode = response.status;
  const data = response.json();
  return Promise
    .all([statusCode, data]);
    .then(res => ({ response: res[0], data: res[1] }));
}`

Answer (score 3):

Because the response of the API in the first `then` is a string not an object, you can't use the response like `response.status`. You should first convert the response to a JSON object and then use the status as `response.status` like the first example. The code should work properly:

```
return fetch(url)
.then(response => {
  const statusCode = response.status;
  let data;
  response.json().then(obj=>{
    data= obj;
    return { statusCode, data };
  });

})
.then(res => {
  console.log("reponse :", res); // <-------- i get a "promise"
 }).catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
  return { name: "network error", description: "" };
});
```

Comment: thanks for help. i agree that it is a string not an object and should be jsonified. but the moment i jsonify it the status is removed from it

Comment: It won't work, `then` with `res` will be called before `then` in `response.json()`.

Comment: I fixed the bug.

Comment: Still incorrect. Also used a few antipatterns (nested promises, closures).